# How to convert a vector with strings into number?

Tags: r

I have a vector of runs scored by a batsmen. He scored 28, 36, 99*, 88, 102*
I want to convert all these "*" values in number and write a function for the same.

Comment: Not an RStudio problem, so I've removed the tag. Please read the tag documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub` to extract all the values(`\\D+`) from the vector and wrap them in `as.numeric`, i.e.

```
as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '',c(28, 36, '99*', 88, '102*')))
#[1]  28  36  99  88 102
```